# CakePHP: How can I select all elements of one category with a "nice" url? (/category/NAME_OF_CATEGORY)

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

right now I have two Tables. Categories and websites. I have a category called Cars (id:5) and two websites belonging to that category (bmw.com, toyota.com).
If I currently want to see all Cars' websites I use the normal url /categories/view/5. But I'd like to have a url like /categories/cars/ to view the same page. So basically instead of an action I need a name of a row in the categories table.

Can you help me to archieve this?
Thank you
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're asking you need to make changes to two things:

- The `app/Config/route.php` file.
- The `app/Controller/CategoriesController.php` file.

On `app/Config/route.php`:

```
Router::connect('/categories/:name', array(
       'controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'viewByName'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => 'name',
        'name' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
    )
);
```

On `app/Controller/CategoriesController.php`:

```
public function viewByName($name = null) {
    $option = array(
        'conditions' => array('Category.name'=>$name)
    );
    $category = $this->Category->find('first', $options);
    $this->set('category', $category);
}
```

You can then copy the contents of `app/View/Categories/view.ctp` into `viewByName.ctp` and polish it a bit.

I give you the bare minimums, so please add checking variable contents for security reasons and so on.

You can also have more insight on this by having a look at the [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) page on [Cake Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But you just forgot to add a + or * after your rule for the name. So it should be `'name' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'`

Comment: Absolutely correct, I'll edit my code. I always seam to forget that little detail :)

Comment: I would add - use special field which stores the url friendly name, because category names containing 2 or more words wont display correctly. Just ad an slug field where you can populate it's value on create with Inflector::slug($this->request->data['Category']['name']);

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy - just read through the very in-depth documentation on routing and you'll have it solved in minutes:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html